# Database Design-struggling with relationships and FKs

Tags: database, database-design

I am building a website which requires a database. I want users to be able to

1. Log into the website (so user details need to be preserved)
2. Search for resources
3. Search for e-books
4. Add resources/ebooks to personal library

I have created four tables
User, Resources, Ebooks, Library

User table consists of the following fields

```
User_ID
User_first_name
User_Last_name
Username
User_password (encrypted)
User_Email
```

Resources consist of the following fields

```
Resource_ID
Resource_Name
Resource_Category
```

Ebooks consist of the following fields

```
Ebook_ID
Ebook_name
Ebook_category
```

Library consists of the following fields

```
Library_ID
User_ID
```

I'm struggling with the relationships and FKs. I have created a relationship between the user and the library as 1 user will have 1 library however, I want users to be able to add as many books/resources as they want to their personal library so what would the relationship between the user and the resources/ebook be?

This may be a really easy solution but I'm new to databases so don't judge!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Time to read a published academic textbook on information modeling & database design. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not textbooks on doing information modeling & database design.) Ask a question about being stuck following it. PS There is no one "the relationship" between/on any particular things. A table represents a relation(ship)/associations among things. You need to tell us what ones you are interested in. Eg "user [user_Id] has resource [resource_id] in their library"? PS Are you maybe stuck re modeling books as (sub)types of resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question, I understand/assume that a resource/ebook can be in many libraries and a library can contain many resources/ebook (many-to-many)

Hence we can create the mapping table as follows:

```
ResourceLibraryMap
----------------
resource_id
library_id

EbookLibraryMap
-------------
ebook_id
library_id
```

By this way, we have created a many_to_many relationship between library-resources and library-ebooks. 
Hence, user will have many resources/ebooks through ResourceLibraryMap/EbookLibraryMap respectively

Comment: Yes your understanding is correct, I believe this will solve my problem. Thank you very much.